# How to get listboxselected item path to process?

Tags: c#, process, fileinfo

I have a listbox which I want file names  on it. You ll able to open when you doubleclick on it. My problem is when I get files to "files" ( List) and add them to listboxt with " files[randomchoose].name" it cant be opened with Process.Start(((FileInfo)listBox1.SelectedItem).FullName); 
It works when you add full paths to listbox. But I want only file names on the listbox.

What I tried:

```
         List<FileInfo> filepaths= new List<FileInfo>();
                   ....
           public void GetFiles(string dir)
    {
          foreach (string ft in filetypes)
              { 
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir, string.Format("*.{0}", ft), SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                files.Add(new FileInfo(file));
                   }

               ....                                   
      filepaths.Add(files[randomchoose]);
       .......
        listBox1.DataSource=filepaths;

          .....
              Process.Start((filepaths[listBox1.SelectedIndex]))
```

But, I cant assign filepaths[] names to listBox1.DataSource. and also Process.Start((filepaths[listBox1.SelectedIndex])) doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to consider using of WPF.

With WPF you will be able to create your own DataTemplate telling the ListBoxItem to show only the FileInfo.Name Property, but "behind" it will still have the needed FullPath Property set and ready to use...

Additionaly there you can define SelectedItem, so you will "automatically" have the needed object instantiated as soon as the selection in the GUI is done. So the double-click can be implemented without many coding work.

Here sample implementation (sorry just quick, dirty and ugly ... BUT...) working just as you want.

XAML (CAVE: ListBox.ItemTemplate where you are telling that you wish to show Property Name in a TextBlock as DataTemplate of the ListBoxItem, and that the selected element is bound to Property in your main window):

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxFiles.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FileList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentFile, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"
             MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_MouseDoubleClick">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="browse" Grid.Row="1" Width="50" Height="30"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

C# (CAVE: using of INotifyPropertyChanged, define your List of FileInfos and the CurrentFile as Properties, handle of the double-click event). I added simple button to show multiselection FileOpenDialog so it can fill the list...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ListBoxFiles
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    private List<FileInfo> _fileList;


    public List<FileInfo> FileList
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileList;
        }

        set
        {
            _fileList = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("FileList");
        }

    }

    private FileInfo _currentFile;

    public FileInfo CurrentFile
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentFile;
        }

        set
        {
            _currentFile = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentFile");
        }
    }



    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //ListBox caller = (ListBox)sender;
        //FileInfo fi = (FileInfo)caller.SelectedItem;
        //Process.Start(fi.FullName);
        Process.Start(this.CurrentFile.FullName);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        bool dialogResult = (bool)ofd.ShowDialog();

        if (dialogResult)
        {
            this._fileList = new List<FileInfo>();
            FileInfo fi;
            foreach (string filename in ofd.FileNames)
            {
                fi = new FileInfo(filename);
                this._fileList.Add(fi);
            }

            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("FileList");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps bind a Dictionary to the ListBox? The key could be the displayed file name and the value (not visible to the user) would be what you'd use in Process.Start()

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/e1317f/how-to-bind-dictionarykeyvalue-pair-to-list-box-and-dropdown-list/